# Using the controls I have in one class with another class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, object, mvvm

I am new to WPF and C#. What is the best way to access the controls or objects (such as textboxes, buttons, etc) in another class. Below explains my situation. I am also using MEF if this makes a difference. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You.

EsriMapView.xaml is where all of the objects are contained.
The class for this is EsriMapView.xaml.cs.

EsriMapViewModel.cs is the other class that I am trying to access EsriMapView.xaml from. The error I receive on all of the object is "The name *blank* does not exist in the current context."

Here is the code from the xaml class:

```
[Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public partial class EsriMapView : DialogWindowBase
    {
        //private int? initialZoom = null;
        //private double? latitude = null;
        //private double? longitude = null;

        //private string json = string.Empty;
        //private ObservableCollection<LocationPoint> marks = null;
        //private bool isZoomToBounds = false;

        //private string startPoint = string.Empty;
        //private string endPoint = string.Empty;

        //private string searchPoint = string.Empty;

        public EsriMapView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        [Import]
        public EsriMapViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return this.DataContext as EsriMapViewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                this.DataContext = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I am also using MVVM. If you need any more information, just let me know. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to access your view from your view model. This breaks one of the tenets of MVVM, which makes testing your VMs difficult. Instead, your VM should expose properties to which the view binds. The VM then has access to the data it needs to do its job.

As a simple example, suppose your view model needs to know the current zoom level in order to perform some calculation. In your view model, you would have:

```
public double Zoom
{
    get { return this.zoom; }
    set
    {
        if (this.zoom != value)
        {
            this.zoom = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Zoom);
        }
    }
}

private void DoSomeCalculation()
{
    // can use this.zoom here
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding Zoom}"/>
```

Comment: So what do you think I should do about enabling and disabling certain objects

Comment: @JLott: again, your VM exposes properties (probably boolean properties in the case of enabling controls) and the view binds to those properties (probably `IsEnabled` in this case). You will need a converter on the binding in this case, because the source type (`bool`) does not match the target type (`Visibility`). See [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx).